# How to give priority between 2 !important

Tags: html, css

IN order to keep the CSS rule I want for a div I have to add: "padding-left:70px!important" to apply generally.

but for the mobile, i would like padding-left:0px.
So I simply add to the media query of the mobile size "padding-left:0px!Important"

So I thought that automatically when switching to mobile size it will take the CSS style inside the media query as the one to use as both have!Important.
But does not happen, it still keeps the 75px padding.

Thanks

Comment: Another good reason to avoid !important at all costs. Anyway, does the media queried one come after the 70px one?

Comment: can you add your css?, The only way to do that is to NOT use !important at all

Answer (score 1):

Order matters, later one with `!important` will overwrite previous (`!important`) one, see example below, whatever media query works for your mobile, make sure you order them correctly

(move your global CSS to top, and media query to bottom)

```css
.test {
  color: red !important;
}

.test {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">TEST TEST TEST</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS styles will take the **most specific** rule you supply, so make sure that your `padding-left:0px!important` rule is still more specific than the one declaring `padding-left:70px!important`.

If the specificity is identical, then CSS will use the last rule defined, so also ensure that your mobile override appears **after** the initial `padding-left` rule.

This is where you can check and understand specificity: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

Bonus: calculate selector specificity: https://specificity.keegan.st/